# How to make "column 0: rownames" a number starting at 1 like a regular dataset in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe with column 0 having the variables:

[image: my dataframe]

How do I get this dataframe to have column 0 as the numbered column and the current column 0 to be a "variable" column (which would be column 1)? I have shown an example below:

[image: my outcome]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rownames_to_column` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
df1 <- rownames_to_column(df1, "Variable")
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Variable <- row.names(df1)
row.names(df1) <- NULL
```